# remove hyphenation at the end of line only regex python r

Tags: python, r, regex

I have a bunch of PDF files (text-based and scanned) to read the text from. There are some cases, where a long word is hyphenated at the end of the line. An example text is attached:

[image: example]

I need to clean these hyphens when they are at the end of line only. That is, I want to keep all the punctuation, and hyphens, otherwise. So in this example, `The-example-text` should stay as it is, but after cleaning line break and hyphen, I want to get `Persönlichkeit`, `Gemeinschaft` and `Fähigkeiten` without hyphens and without empty spaces instead of hyphen.

What I do in R is:

```
gsub("-\n\n|-\n|- \n", "", txt)
```

But this does not work always.
What is the elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This would do it for you:

```
-\s*$\s+
```

- `-\s*$` - capture a `-` with optional whitespace at the end of a line
- `\s+` - capture any whitespaces (including new lines) after the dash

In your replacement just replace with an empty string.

If the above is not compatible in R then this should be per http://www.endmemo.com/r/gsub.php:

```
-[[:space:]]*$[[:space:]]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/hTaKYC/1

Comment: In R I don't think `\s` is recognized, should probably be replaced with `-[:blank:]*$`

Comment: why o you have to put `\s` in a character class?

Comment: @Onyambu Botched edit, it used to be `[\r\n]`. It's fixed though...

Comment: @Alexlok yes `\s` is recognized in R. R uses `POXIS` engine by default and also uses `PCRE` when the user states so. The only issue is you have to escape the backslash just like in many other languages.

Comment: @Alexlok `python` is tagged so I assumed this would be okay.

Comment: @Alexlok I think you might be right, replaced `\s` with `[:space:]`

Comment: @Onyambu `\s` in R is different than `\s` in normal regex

Comment: No, I think Onyambu was right, it worked with `\\s`, my bad

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What exactly do you mean? R uses POXIS and PCRE engines. So I dont get your point

Comment: Even in python you need to escape the backslash unless you indicate that it is a raw string. ie `r'\s'` otherwise you need to use `\\s`. Also in R, i believe version >4.0, you can indicate that a string is raw by putting `r` in front of it ie `r(\s)`. of course in perl you do not need to escape the backslash. But in most of the languages including `c++` you need to escape the backslash

Comment: @Alexlok According to http://www.endmemo.com/r/gsub.php `\\s` is for space only and `[:space:]` is for whitespace

Comment: @Onyambu See http://www.endmemo.com/r/gsub.php. I'm not an R expert so just going based on what I understand in the docs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus. as i stated earlier, R uses both PCRE and POXIS engines. `\s` means exactly the same in R as in any PCRE engine. Try doing `gsub('\\s', '', 'delete \n\r ')` or even `sub('\\s+', '', 'delete \n\r ')` and you will note that it will delete all the ` \n\r`

Comment: I dont recall what type of engine that python uses, but I know its not PCRE. It does not allow for recursions or breaks or look behinds of unspecified length more than 1 etc. But i believe the `regex` modules does cater for some of these issues

Comment: @Onyambu Actually, the default regex library used in base R regex functions is not just POSIX, it is called [TRE](https://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/), which is POSIX-based.

Answer (score 2):

You could try fiddling with `gsubfn::gsubfn` to distinguish whether the hyphen connects two words or just wraps one:

```
gsubfn(pattern = "-\\n\\s*[A-Z]?", replacement = function(x) {
  if (grepl(pattern = "[A-Z]", x = x)) {
    gsub("\\n\\s?|\\n\\s+", "", x)
  } else {
    gsub("-\\n\\s?", "", x)
  }
}, x = x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import re

# replace all '-\n','- \n', '-  \n', '-\n\n'
result = re.sub(r'- *\n+','', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove any hyphen that is followed by optional spaces and then any amount of line endings:

```r
gsub("-\\h*\\R+", "", txt, perl=TRUE)
library(stringr)
stringr::str_replace_all(txt, "-\\h*\\R+", "")
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/BcjPdh/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \h*                      horizontal whitespace, 0 or more times
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \R+                      any line ending (1 or more times)
```